# Azure StartCopyBlob only copied by Uri?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I was writing some code to copy another blob and was using some code from another project as a template. But my blob.StartCopy in my new project only wants a URI. In my other project, the StartCopy method has 3 overloads, one which takes a blob, which is what I wanted to do. So I guess I'm not referencing something I should?

```
Refence                                                      Old       New
Microsoft.Azure.Storage                                      5.0.2.0   8.1.1.0
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Common.Blob.Transfer    3.8.0.5   3.8.0.5
```

Here's the code...

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(  CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_avStorageContainerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(imageName);
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(testFileName))
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        IAsset asset = _context.Assets.Create(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), AssetCreationOptions.None);
        IAccessPolicy writePolicy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create("writePolicy", TimeSpan.FromDays(30), AccessPermissions.Write);
        var newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
                 ILocator destinationLocator = _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, asset, writePolicy)
        Uri uploadUri = new Uri(destinationLocator.Path);
        var assetContainerName = uploadUri.Segments[1];
        CloudBlobContainer assetContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(assetContainerName);
        var mediaBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_avStorageContainerName);
        mediaBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        var sourceCloudBlob = mediaBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(imageName);
        sourceCloudBlob.FetchAttributes();
        IAssetFile assetFile = asset.AssetFiles.Create(imageName);
        var destinationBlob = container.GetBlobReference(imageName);
        if (destinationBlob.Exists())
             destinationBlob.DeleteIfExists();
        destinationBlob.StartCopy(sourceCloudBlob);
```

> And here's copy of my references. They are all the latest from NuGet.
>   Maybe I missed something?

[image]

Comment: I'm using the same version and I can see the three overloads one of them is CloudBlobBlob as source - https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6c5U.png.

Comment: I know they should be there, the question is why aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know why this is happening. The problem is with the following line of code:

```
var destinationBlob = container.GetBlobReference(imageName);
```

Basically here you're creating an instance of type [`CloudBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.aspx) and it's [`StartCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.startcopy.aspx) method only accepts a Uri (there are no other overloads).

What you would need to do is get a reference for [`CloudBlockBlob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.aspx) and it's `StartCopy` method has other overloads as well.

```
var destinationBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(imageName);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.